# iOS - Text doesnt appear when typing but does when scrolling

Tags: ios, css, angular, ionic2

I'm creating an ionic 2 mobile application.

On Android and Windows, this issue doesn't occur.

On my page I have 2 inputs. 1 for the title and 1 for the description.

When I tap these and start typing, everything works fine. But when I first scroll for even a little and then tap my input and start typing, Only the first letter is shown and the rest remains blank.

After the user has typed something and it remains blank but then scrolls even a little (while still having focus on input), the text appears.

My html: (full)

```
<ion-content #content padding>
         <img *ngIf="imageSrc" #image class="taken-image" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageSrc)"/> 

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="white-text" inline>Title</ion-label>

                <!-- Issue #1 -->
<!-- HERE -->   <ion-input style="z-index: 9999999999999999999" [(ngModel)]="imageData.title" placholder="Enter a title" (onkeyup)="changedInput()"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item class="item-no-padding">
                <button class="blue-button" outline ion-button block icon-left tappable (click)="selectCat()"><ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>Select Cats</button>
                <div *ngIf="selectedCats">
                    Selected Cat(s):
                    <ion-list>
                        <ion-item class="close-item" *ngFor="let spot of selectedCats">
                            {{spot.value}}
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </div>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item class="item-no-padding">
                <button class="blue-button" outline ion-button block icon-left tappable (click)="selectCat1()"><ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>Select Cat1</button>
                <div *ngIf="selectedCat1">
                    Selected Cat1:
                    <ion-list>
                        <ion-item class="close-item" *ngFor= "let spot of selectedCat1">
                            {{spot.value}}
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </div>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item class="item-no-padding">
                <!--<ion-textarea class="text-area" [(ngModel)]="description" placeholder="Enter a description (optional)" (onkeyup)="changedInput()" clearInput>
                </ion-textarea> -->


<!-- HERE -->   <textarea style="z-index: 999999999999999999999" [(ngModel)]="description" placeholder="Enter a description" (onkeyup)="changedInput()"></textarea>
            </ion-item>


        </ion-list>  

        <div class="send-button-wrapper">
            <p class="send-button" (click)="send()"><span class="send-button-text">Send</span>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ion-fab class="send-button" color="main-text"><ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon></button></p>
        </div>

        <white-leaves-background></white-leaves-background>
</ion-content>
```

So here I have already tried setting the `z-index` over 9000 but the issue remained.

I also tried adding an `onkeyup` event where I tried to 'fake' a scroll without result.

My `ts` code (the relevant, juicy bits):

```
changedInput(event:any) { 
    // fake scroll, no effect       
    window.scrollBy(0, 2);

    // setting description as a test
    this.description = event.target.value;
}
```

That's it really, I don't modify DOM elements from my typescript in this class.

And my `scss` thought it might be a css issue so I'll add it as well

```
.item-no-padding {
    .item-inner {
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
}
.fab ion-icon {
    font-size: 3.4rem;
}

.send-button-wrapper {
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
    margin-top: 25%;
    text-align: right;
}

.send-button-text {
    font-size: 3.4rem;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10%
}

.send-button {
    margin-top: -10%;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.close-item {
    min-height: 3.4rem !important;
    ion-label {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}

.taken-image {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.text-area {
    height: 80px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

::placeholder {
    color: black !important;
}

image-edit{

    .app-background {
        img {
            filter: opacity(25%);
        }
    }

    ion-label {
        margin: 13px 0 13px 0 !important;
    }

    ion-input {
        .button {
            background-color: transparent;
            color: white;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
    }

    .very-important-to-show {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .item-button {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 40px !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center !important;
        color: white !important;
        border: none !important;
    }

    .card, .item {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
    }

}
```

**important notes**

- The `onkeyup` isn't in the original code, I tried this as a solution but failed.
- The original code also used an `ion-textarea` instead of `textarea`.
- Already reinstalled `ionic-plugin-keyboard` -> version 2.2.1 & 2.2.4 (I think)
- The text **does** show after scrolling and you can see the cursor move
- When typing a g, q, p etc. you can even see the parts that exceed the normal line (q and p shows the line for example) like something is just hovering on top of the exact line I'm typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for some reason, after adding `transform: translateZ(0px);` on my text-area and input field. And after adding a 'fake' induced scroll which doesn't actually scroll:

`<ion-content> ...... </ion-content>`

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

....

@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

....

changedInput() {
  // scroll the content to the same place in 1ms
  this.content.scrollTo(0, 0, 1);
}
```

This doesn't scroll, no matter how big your content is. This is relative to the body tag.

Comment: Not sure which of these solved the issue, but I keep both since testing on iOS is quite difficult for me atm.

Comment: I had the same issue on iOS safari in-app facebook browser with a textarea input (might also be an issue with the default mobile iOS safari browser). The first letter would appear but then no letters would show up after the first until a scroll was performed. I fixed it with just `transform: translateZ(0px);` on the textarea so I don't know how necessary the scrollTo is. Hope this can also help anyone else with a similar issue.